# How to access getSupportFragmentManager in ComponentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, android-appcompat

I want access `getSupportFragmentManager` in `ComponentActivity`.
Working with jetpack compose and I need to use a fragment which is available from a third party SDk.

Any help/clue is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to extend [**`AppCompatActivity`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity) or [**`FragmentActivity`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity) instead of [`ComponentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity).

Comment: Thanks it worked, actually I was hesitant to use them thinking that it wo'nt let me work with composables

Comment: @AliNawaz Pls note that AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity which extends ComponentActivity. ComponentActivity has all you need for a Compose-only app.
If you need AppCompat APIs or you need Fragments then use AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I;m changing to AppCompatActivity but then on my AndroidManifests.xml needs to set the theme to AppCompat.

Does change this theme make me unable to use materialYou dynamic color?